# Holomorphic functions to complex torus

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $X$ be a complex algebraic variety and $T$ a complex torus (not necessarily algebraic).

Assume that $X$ is a proper subset of its completion  $\bar{X}$.

Let $f:X \to T$ be a holomorphic map.
Are there any conditions on $f$ that imply it can be extended to a holomorphic map $ \bar{f}: \bar{X} \to T $?

Comment: Certainly not in general: take $X=\mathbb{A}^1$, $\overline{X}=\mathbb{P}^1$, $T$ an elliptic curve, and $f:X\rightarrow T$ its universal covering.

Comment: @abx Thank you for the comment. The question was edited to be a bit too general. I am aware that you cannot extend the map in general, I was wondering if there are conditions on $f$ that imply it can be extended.

Comment: @user141601, you can roll back unwanted edits.